# Что нужно сделать чтобы убрать приложение из списка неоптимизированных под fullscreen?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Основа приложения Xamarin. Подключил режим fullscreen по умолчанию таким образом:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Пытался в Resources/AndroidManifest android:resizeableActivity ставить как true, так и false

Но из этого меню приложение не пропадает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути результатом приложение должно пропасть из списка не оптимизированных под fullscreen